# Separation of Variables for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Determine whether the Method of Separation of Variables can be used to turn the following PDE into two ODEs.

$u_{xx}+u_{xy}+u_{yy}+u=0$

I realize that this is an "elliptic PDE", but don't know what change of variables I should try to use.

Comment: The problematic term for separation of variables is $u_{xy}$. You can get ridd of this term by making a change of variables to put the elliptic PDE on so-called [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_partial_differential_equation#Derivation_of_Canonical_Form).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a linear change of variables $X = x, Y = a x + y$ that makes the mixed term vanish.  That is, write $u(x,y) = F(x) G(ax + y)$, and see what value of $a$ gets rid of the term in $F'(x) G'(ax+y)$.

Comment: The downvote is undeserved; the proposed procedure here works.