# Separation of variables for Aronsson's equation in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am working on the following problem
[image]

I don't seem to get it done. I've tried with $u(x_1,x_2)=v(x_1)w(x_2)$ and got the following
$$w^3(v')^2v''+2wv(w')^2(v')^2+v^3(w')^2w''=0.$$
But this doesn't help since no matter what I do, I get terms involving both $v$ and $w$.

Then I found this post: [Separation of Variables for PDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656162/separation-of-variables-for-pde)

I tried that change of variables in that post and after a lengthy calculations I still did not get rid off the mixed terms. Any help on this one? The problem is from Evans book on PDEs from chapter 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$w^3(v')^2v''+2wv(w')^2(v')^2+v^3(w')^2w''=0.$$
$$\frac{(v')^2v''}{v^3}+2\left(\frac{v'}{v}\right)^2\left(\frac{w'}{w}\right)^2+\frac{(w')^2w''}{w^3}=0 $$
Among several possibilities : Let $\frac{v'}{v}=\lambda=$constant.
$$v(x_1)=c_1e^{\lambda x_1}\qquad\lambda=\text{constant}$$
$$\lambda^4+2\lambda^2\left(\frac{w'}{w}\right)^2+\frac{(w')^2w''}{w^3}=0 $$
Solving for $w(x_2)$ would lead to many solutions. More simply, among those solutions :
$$w(x_2)=c_2e^{\mu x_2}\qquad\mu=\text{constant}$$
with condition
$$\lambda^4+2\lambda^2\mu^2+\mu^4=0 $$
$$\mu=\pm i\:\lambda$$
$$u(x_1,x_2)=v(x_1)w(x_2)=c\:e^{\lambda(x_1\pm i\:x_2)}$$
The constants $c$ and $\lambda$ can be complex. Real solutions with sinusoidal functions can be derived instead of exponential of complex variable.

Comment: Now I get it, I was trying to get some sort of general solution, but the idea is to get just some solution. I think one idea is to look for solutions with $v''=\lambda v$.